# extract first element array with Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I m new to Jolt, i m trying to achieve the following :

Input :

```
{
  "A": [1,2,3],
  "B": "b",
  "C": ["4","5","6"]
}
```

output :

```
{
  "A" : 1,
  "B" : "b",
  "C" : "4"
}
```

I need to extract the first element if the key is an array,keep the key-value as it is in other cases.
I come up with the following expression :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "0": "&1"
      },
      "B": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

The problem here is that i have to specify "B" key, since i can have a lot of those keys this solution it's not good for me.
There is a way to do it without specify all key names?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the firstElement list function from modify-overwrite-beta

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=firstElement(@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```